# How to convert pandas <NA> to numy Nan?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following data set

[image]

I would like to convert float values to int, so i did `data.convert_dtypes()`

[image]

Pandas converted Nan to Na. How can i make it back or prevent pandas to do it? I use data imputation and some algorithmes doesn't support  ( `'bool' object has no attribute 'transpose'` )

I tried `replace`, `fillna` . `Replace({pd.NA: np.nan})` convert int to float back again and this is not my solution since i would like to work with int

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need `np.nan`, which is float, `NA integer` columns are converted to `float` columns:

```
df = df.replace({pd.NA: np.nan})
```

If you need integers, the only way is to replace `NA` with some integer:

```
df = df.replace(pd.NA, -1)
```

Comment: Yea, i tried it, it makes all values to float, but i need integers..

Comment: @AlexNikitin - Then impossible, if need replace `integers Na` to `NaN` get always floats.

Comment: @AlexNikitin - Only possible replace NaN to some intgers like `-1`, then get integers, but there are no `NaN`, no `NA` values

Comment: First path falls with C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace)
   2416         # to_replace is a dict, are handled separately in NDFrame
   2417         for replace_value, new_value in replace_dict.items():
-> 2418             if new_value == replace_value:
   2419                 continue
   2420             if replace_value in cat.categories:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\missing.pyx in pandas._libs.missing.NAType.__bool__()

TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

Comment: it does not replace anything :(

Comment: For me, only this worked: df[col] = np.where(df[col].isna(), np.nan, df[col]). With "col" being a column name. Using it with a looping for all columns or another way to make it work with all columns at once, should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used `df = df.replace(pd.NA, None)`. The problem is that converts the column type to `object`, but not `None` values in the column are still `int` so you can determine column type like this

```
type(df['int_col'].dropna().values[0])
```