# Plotly dash error loading layout. The only thing different is nulls and nans

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am writing a script to display a table with dash.
It is not working, right now it shows "Error Loading Layout" as an error.

Now I investigated further into other answers in SO and the dataframe I displayed in my table first like this

```
app.layout= dash_table.DataTable(data_all.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in data_all.columns ]  )
```

and then like this

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        dash_table.DataTable(
            columns= [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in data_all.columns ],
            data=data_all.to_dict('records'), 
            
             )
    ]
    )
```

Neither of them work.

Turns out I have the following situation:

With my original dataframe `data_all`
I have

```
 data_all.isnull().any().any()
True
```

Then I change *only the dataframe* for

```
data_all = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')
data_all.isnull().any().any()
```

and this gives
False

with this dataframe the application displays without problems.

So it seems the original dataframe has some problems that dont permit it to be shown in the table

How can I find these probles and display the dataframe in the browser?

EDIT1:

I made further experiments.

When I insert a new row containing np.nan, there is no problem
When I cut my dataframe to the place before Nan appears, there is no problem

The problem seems to appear when a new row  contains

like

datasource datavalue  value2 value3

```
.....
 150 aaaa.pdf    <NA>    0       NaN
```

So perhaps the solution is a way to replace  with NaN ?

Comment: Did you try to drop `NaN`-values using `df.dropna()` befor plotting the data?

Comment: No, I didn't. And the reason is that I wish that those spaces with Nan appear also in the table.  Those are rows like  ` datasource   datavalue
0  aaaa.pdf     Nan ` or <NA>`  Maybe I could replace those Nan with a string"NAN"?

Comment: @mosc9575 And made further experiment and `np.nan` seems not to be the problem. What is null and what is the difference with nan?

Comment: Looks like it is the same, see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37878/difference-between-isna-and-isnull-in-pandas.

Comment: Can you print the head of you DataFrame to reproduce?

Comment: I added a Edit. The first 149 rows seemnot to have a problem. Even when I insert np.Nan dont have a problem. But the row 150 has <NA> there. That generates the problem

Comment: Something related in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068605/how-to-convert-pandas-na-to-numy-nan

Comment: What is the type of `<NA>`. Looks like the source of you problem.