# TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous when using np.where() to compare string columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm importing a feather into a pandas dataframe and then looking to compare two string columns using np.where(). However, I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous`. An MRE is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {"col1": [np.NaN, "x"], "col2": [np.NaN, "x"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_feather("test.feather")
df_f = pd.read_feather("test.feather")
df_f["col1"] = df_f["col1"].astype("string")
df_f["col2"] = df_f["col2"].astype("string")
df_f["is_equal"] = np.where(df_f["col1"] == df["col2"], 1, 0)
```

I had to manually format the two columns as strings to replicate the format of the actual dataframe when I import it.

I've read up on the error and it's to do with the `pd.NA` values that are created when the columns are converted into strings.

I've tried converting these values to `np.NaN` as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068615/11277108):

```
df_f["col1"].replace({pd.NA: np.NaN}, inplace=True)
df_f["col2"].replace({pd.NA: np.NaN}, inplace=True)
```

But I get the same error.

I've tried converting the column to a float as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73041862/11277108):

```
df_f["col1"] = df_f["col1"].astype("float")
df_f["col2"] = df_f["col2"].astype("float")
```

But I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float`.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to how I might be able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original `object` dtype, comparison with `NA` or `None` value will coerce result to False.

```
$ df_f["col1"] == df["col2"]

0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

When you convert the column to `string` dtype, comparison with `NA` or `None` value won't coerce result to False.

```
$ df_f["col1"] = df_f["col1"].astype("string")
$ df_f["col1"] == df["col2"]

0    <NA>
1    True
dtype: boolean
```

For `np.where`, it accepts an array of boolean values, thus it doesn't understand what `NA` is and throws the TypeError.

For the string column, `object` dtype is the standard type you don't need convert it to string dtype. If you really want to do that and make comparison, you can try

```
df_f["is_equal"] = np.where(df_f["col1"].eq(df["col2"]).fillna(False), 1, 0)
# or
df_f["is_equal"] = df_f["col1"].eq(df["col2"]).fillna(False).astype(int)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I simply create an ordinary df (no use of feather) with `pd.NA` in place of `np.NaN` values in your original df, `np.where` works fine.

However, if I first update each column using `astype("string")`, changing the dtypes of the columns to `string` from `object`, I get your error.

Therefore, I believe `astype("string")` is the culprit, and I would try eliminating the assignments that call this method.

Comment: Hi. As per my question the `astype("string")` are only there to replicate the actual dataframe when I import it. This is an MRE not the actual code...

Comment: In that case, perhaps you could use `np.where` first, and after that do the `astype("string")` conversion.